# QML Map not zooming to cursor

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML map created that when zooming via scroll, zooms to the center of the map as opposed to zooming to the cursor location. From another SO answer, I came to the conclusion that this should be a default behavior, but it is not working that way for me.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtLocation 5.5
import QtPositioning 5.5

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Mapper"
    id: mapWindow
    x: Screen.width / 2 - width / 2
    y: Screen.height / 2 - height / 2
    width: 1400
    height: 800
    visible: true
    color: "#0b2f5c"

    Map
    {
        id: basemap
        objectName: "basemap"
        property string inputStr: "import QtQuick 2.0; import QtLocation 5.0; import QtPositioning 5.0; "
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: 300
        anchors.leftMargin: 25
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        anchors.bottomMargin: 50
        plugin: Plugin
        {
            name: "osm"
            PluginParameter
            {
                name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"
                value: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/"
            }
        }
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(0, 0)
        zoomLevel: 2
        minimumZoomLevel: 2
    }
}
```

I am launching the window with `QQmlApplicationEngine` in C++

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine* engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(QUrl("<path to file>"));
QObject* topLevel = mEngine->rootObjects().value(0);
QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(mTopLevel);

window->show();
```

What is going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the other SO answer? Do you have a link?

Comment: @squ1dd13 Yes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182832/qml-map-zoom-only-verticaly

Comment: "but it is not working that way for me" - What does it do instead?

Comment: @JarMan It is zooming to the center of the map, as in the center of the current displayed area.